# trigger Informatica workflow based on the status column in oracle table

Tags: informatica

I want to implement the below scenario without using pl/sql procedure or trigger

1. I have a table called emp_details with coulmns (empno,ename,salary,emp_status,flag,date1) .
2. If someone updates the columns `emp_status='abc'` and `flag='y'`, `Informatica WF 1` would be in continuous running status and checking emp_status value "ABC"
3. If it found record / records then query all the records and it will invoke WF 2.
4. WF 1 will pass value ename,salary,Date1 to WF 2 (Wf2 will populate will insert the records into the table emp_details2).

How can I do this using the informatica approach instead of plsql or trigger?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve this in real time, write the output of WF1 to a message queue and in the second workflow WF2 subscribe to the message queue produced from WF1.

If you have batch process in place. Produce a output file from WF1 and use this output file in WF2. You can easily setup this dependency using job schedulers.

Comment: Hi Bharadwaj, Thanks for your reply. but I dnt have any knowledege in message queue concepts.. could you please eloborate on ths more?

Comment: Hi, you can create a message queue using JMS which is free or can use IBM Websphere for MQ. Then from Informatica you can create MQ Sources and Targets and then you have to create connection to that queue. Use that connection to either read or write the data on queue. How to create MQ is probably out of scope, because lots of coding and config setup is required.

Comment: Hi Bhardwaj, Is there any other way without using message queues?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why do you need two workflows in the first place. Why not accomplish `emp_details2` table updates with the very same workflow that is looking for differences.

Anyway, this can be done using indicator file:

1. WF1 running continously should create a file if any changes have been found.
2. WF2 should be running continously with `EventWait` set to wait for the indicator file specified above. Once found it should use the `Assignment Task` to rename/delete the file and fetch the desired data from source and populate the `emp_details2` table.

If you need it this way, you can pass the data through the indicator file

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a single workflow, Create a dummy session which which check for the flag in table after this divide the flow into two based on the below link conditions,

Flow one: Link condition, Session.Status=SUCCEEDED and SOURCE_SUCCESS_ROWS(count)>=1 then run your actual session which will load the data

Flow two: Link Condition, Session.Status=SUCCEEDED and SOURCE_SUCCESS_ROWS=0, connect this to control task and mark the workflow as complete.

Make sure you schedule the workflow at Informatica level to run continousuly.

Cheers